# clearTimeout on a function that has a paramenter

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I am writing a chat application that can have many chat windows open at once.  Every time a window is opened I call a setInterval on my function, update_chat(), that updates an individual chat window.  I pass the chat_id to update_chat()

```
setInterval("update_chat("+chat_id+")",4000);
```

`chat_id` is just the id of the chat.  So I can have the function `update_chat` running multiple times on different intervals depending on how many chats are open.  Start the chat works fine.

My main question is how can I stop the interval above.  I don't want to stop all intervals, just the one associated with a particular chat.  I tried this

```
clearInterval("update_chat("+chat_id+")");
```

but it didn't do anything.

---

I tried

`var chat_intervals=[]`

`chat_intervals[chat_id]=setInterval("update_chat("+chat_id+")",4000);`

`clearInterval(chat_intervals[end_id]);`

It didn't stop the interval

Comment: Don't pass a string into `setInterval`!

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 why not?  I have to pass that function a parameter.  How else could I get the parameter to the function?

Comment: Because passing a string is the same as using `eval`. The correct (safe) way of passing a parameter is to wrap an anonymous function around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clearInterval`([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)) takes an interval ID as a parameter to know which interval to clear. `setInterval` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)) returns an interval ID when called, so you store that in a var and pass it to `clearInterval` when you want that one to clear.

```
//start the interval, store its ID
var interval_id = setInterval( function () { /* do something*/ }, 1000);

//clear the interval
clearInterval(interval_id);
```

Note that `setTimeout` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)) and `clearTimeout` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)) work with each other in the same way.

Also note that while `setInterval` can take a string argument as the function to run, it can also take actual functions (which is highly preferred). So your code could be better written as:

```
var update_chat_interval = setInterval(function () {
    update_chat(chat_id);
}, 4000);

// to clear it later:
clearInterval(update_chat_interval);
```

Comment: @Gilberg In your updated code you set the ID to `chat_intervals[chat_id]` but you passed `chat_intervals[end_id]` back to `clearInterval` instead. For clarity, you used **chat_id** and then **end_id**. Also, in your comments on the question you asked how to avoid passing a string to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. The last portion of my answers tells you how.